# JSON not validating

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am trying to send an array of dictionaries but it is failing validation.  Here is an example output:

```
  {
        album = "Karaoke - In the style of Goo Goo Dolls - Vol. 2";
        artist = "Stingray Music (Karaoke)";
        length = "208.404";
        title = "Better Days (Karaoke Version)";
    },
        {
        album = Down;
        artist = "Jay Sean";
        length = "212.61";
        title = Down;
    },
        {
        album = "Growing Pains";
        artist = "Mary J Blige";
        length = "301.844";
        title = "Come to Me (Peace)";
    }
```

Here is the code generating it:

```
NSMutableArray *mutableSongsToSerialize = [NSMutableArray array];
NSArray *songs = [playlist items];              
for (MPMediaItem *song in songs){
       NSString *title =[song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
       NSString *artist =[song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumArtist];
       NSString *album =[song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle];
       NSString *length =[song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration];
       NSDictionary *songDictionary = @{@"title": title, @"artist": artist, @"album":album, @"length":length};
       [mutableSongsToSerialize addObject:songDictionary];
}
NSString *jsonRepresentation = [NSJSONSerialization JSONOBjectWithData:mutableSongsToSerialize options:0 error:NULL];
```

I'm think this line needs to be modified somehow so that each song is not treated as a root element, but im not sure what to do specifically.

> NSDictionary *songDictionary = @{@"title": title, @"artist": artist,
>   @"album":album, @"length":length};

Comment: "I'm think this line needs to be modified somehow to not many each a root, but im not sure what to do specifically." what does that mean?

Comment: Also you should refer to my earlier answer - use the dataWith... Method to serialize, you're trying to deserialize something that's not serialized JSON

Comment: @CarlVeazey - i used the JSONOBjectWithData function so I can see what the output would look like, eventually I want to send it to a webservice.  I've also edited my typo above - I think the problem is each song is being treated as a root element.  If I keep it the origin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using the correct method to serialize your JSON. You need to use `+[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error]`.

Here's an example that uses the same structure as yours but with hard coded values:

```
NSDictionary *song1 = @{@"title": @"title1", @"artist": @"artist1", @"album":@"album1", @"length":@"length1"};
NSDictionary *song2 = @{@"title": @"title2", @"artist": @"artist2", @"album":@"album2", @"length":@"length2"};
NSDictionary *song3 = @{@"title": @"title3", @"artist": @"artist3", @"album":@"album3", @"length":@"length3"};
NSArray *songs = @[song1, song2, song3];
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *JSONData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:songs options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
NSString *JSONDataAsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:JSONData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"JSON String = %@",JSONDataAsString);
NSLog(@"error was %@",error);
```

The output looks like:

```
JSON String = [
  {
    "title" : "title1",
    "album" : "album1",
    "length" : "length1",
    "artist" : "artist1"
  },
  {
    "title" : "title2",
    "album" : "album2",
    "length" : "length2",
    "artist" : "artist2"
  },
  {
    "title" : "title3",
    "album" : "album3",
    "length" : "length3",
    "artist" : "artist3"
  }
]
```

If you don't wish to add Objective-C code to see the string output, you could try the following in lldb:

```
expr (NSString *) [[NSString alloc] initWithData:JSONData encoding:4]
```

`4` is used in place of `NSUTF8StringEncoding` due to visibility issues with the debugger.

Comment: Thanks again for replying, I see the correct way for me to view the output listed in your post, I was converting it to a string all wrong.

Comment: Do you see how I created a string representation of the data? Is that what you're asking? Or something else?

Comment: Yup that's exactly what i was looking for, how to see a string version properly.  Thank you for helping me twice and also helping me understand WHY I was in the wrong.

Comment: @johnhannigan great, I just added how to do it with an lldb command as well.

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON is invalid, you should put `:` instead of `=` and `,` instead of `;`, don't forget to omit the last `'`. Also, the hash keys must be quoted :

```
{
    "album": "Karaoke - In the style of Goo Goo Dolls - Vol. 2",
    "artist": "Stingray Music (Karaoke)",
    "length": "208.404",
    "title": "Better Days (Karaoke Version)"
},
...
```

Also you can use the [JSON lint](http://jsonlint.org) to check your JSONs.